# Rate my Rasberry Pi UPS

Tags: batteries, raspberry-pi, charger, ups

I've made simple schematic for a UPS for Raspberry  Pi. It contains a 12V Lead Acid Battery (40Ah), 5V LM7805 regulator and some capacitors. I'm supposing max 1.2A load from Raspi.
Should I add something? I'm totally noob at designing that type of circuits.[image: This is it]

Comment: Add a massive heatsink because the 7805 will dissipate around 9 W. Or try a buck regulator, such as the ubiquitous 34063.

Comment: Yes, I want to add a heatsink. I don't have any buck regulators at this time.

Comment: Go to any convenience or electronics store and buy a 2 amp usb car charger. You now have a buck regulator with all needed parts.

Comment: Also, this doesn't have any qualities of a UPS, like power failover, diodes, battery charging circuitry. All it is a ~14v battery to 5v usb supply...

Comment: @up I know, about charging i have special charger for that battery. About failover i've implemented algorithm for checking voltage of battery

Comment: "Better", if possible, would be to use a 6V battery and a low drop out regulator. If using a linear regulator, adding a series input resistor to drop as much voltage as the design allows will move heat from regulator to resistor. R = V/I. R<= (Vbat_minimum Vdropoutmax-5V)/1.2. Say 11V, 2.5V so R <= (11-2.5.5)/1.2 = <= 3.5/1.2 ~= 3 Ohms. On startup surges current may be higher. Need high enough Cout to handle surge.

Comment: But 6V battery will lose its voltage quicker than a 12V one. Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: You are wrong :-). Or, if using a linear regulator, anything more than 5V is wasted as heat so a 12V 40Ah battery and a 6V 40 Ah battery will both be the equivalent of an != 5V, 40h supply. Also, you will be able to get 2 x 6v batteries with a combined total of more than 40Ah for the same cost as a 12V 40 Ah battery. A 6V 40 Ah battery will probably cost more than half the price of a 12V 40 Ah battery but overall &=**IF** you use a linear regulator you would get more for your $ from 6V batteries if all were bought new. If you are getting cheap or free used 12V batteries the equations change...

Comment: ... However, if you use a switching regulator [SR] (buck converter, DC-DC converter, SMPS,...) from 12V then the majority of the energy will NOT be wasted as heat. A SR will typically give you 80%-85% efficiency for 12V in and 5V out. Note that if you use an LDO (low dropout)  linear regulator and a 6V battery you will get 5/6 = 84% efficiency. If your 6V battery is a fully charged lead acid Vbat ~= 6.9V and even then efficiency = 5/6.9 =~ 72%. So 6V and a linear regulator is "not too bad". ....

Comment: .... Just for fun department: If you use 12V and an LDO linear regulator you can put 2  series white LEDS* between regulator and bat and get about 6 Watts of LED drive instead of wasting it as heat. * LEDs would need to be able to handle the current. If doing this you could have a current controlled switch which added or removed pairs of series connected LEDs to keep each pair near peak brightness. Sounds like a job for an Arduino :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A linear voltage regulator converts excess power to heat.

So dropping 7V to get 5V is worse than 50% efficiency.

At 0.7A and 7V drop, that would be almost 5W of heat.

So you'll need a decent size heat sink.

Look at DC-DC converters instead if you care about that energy waste.

Edit: to incorporate ACD's comment:
"lead-acid batteries are usually around 14.5V when fully charged. At 1.2A that's 11.4W"

Comment: You mean buck converters?

Comment: Worth noting that lead-acid batteries are usually around 14.5V when fully charged. At 1.2A that's 11.4W! You'd need an unreasonably sized heatsink.

Comment: There are also switch-mode drop-in [replacements](http://www.protostack.com/semiconductors/voltage-regulators/switching-regulator-lm7805-drop-in-replacement) for 7805.

Comment: @ACD - Thank you. I have incorporated your comment, hopefully with adequate credit.

Comment: @AshtonHearts - Thank you very much, I hadn't noticed those before.

Answer (score 2):

Just search for a "5V step-down converter". Any that can handle 16VDC input and is capable of supplying 1A or more will work fine.

Keep in mind that Raspberry has an on-board 3.3V linear regulator, which is a waste of energy on it's own. If efficiency is your goal - I would suggest bypassing the on-board LDO and using a 3.3V step-down (aka buck) converter to power the board. 5V input is only used to power USB and HDMI ports ([source](http://www.daveakerman.com/?page_id=1294)). Therefore, if you don't need any of those peripherals this will be the most efficient solution.

**edit**: I'm assuming you're using model B. There is a newer model which has a switching regulator instead of a linear one.

Answer (score 1):

A typical 7805 is rated at only 1.0A. A Rasberry Pi will draw 1.5 .. 2.0 A when booting. Hence your circuit will probably not work.

Note that it might work when you try it because an 7805 is not guaranteed to deliver only 1.0A, but relying on it to deliver more is walking on thin ice.

Comment: Yes, according to anwsers I'll change my 7805 to a buck converter. But which one?